# Two bivariate polynomials (or rational functions) that generate $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, birational-geometry

Let $f=f(x,y),g=g(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$, each of degree $\geq 1$, and $f,g$ are algebraically independent over $\mathbb{C}$ (= their Jacobian $\in \mathbb{C}[x,y]-\{0\}$).

> **(1)** Is there a sufficient condition that will guarantee that $\mathbb{C}(f,g)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$?

Perhaps it would help if we will consider $f$ and $g$ as polynomials in one variable $y$ over $\mathbb{C}(x) \subset \bar{\mathbb{C}(x)}$?

A related question I have asked is [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2772853/two-polynomials-generating-mathbbcx-y2), but I have not got an answer for it, so I decided to ask the above related question here, hoping to get some additional help.

**A remark:** I have just found three relevant papers: [1](https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0219498815400058), [2](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.0154) and
[3](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.3752.pdf), where the last one seems to answer my question (Theorem 1.10, or more accurately, since here the base field is of characteristic zero, Theorem 1.10 in characteristic zero is a result of K.P. Russell "Field generators in two variables", J. Math. Kyoto Univ., 1.

> **(2)** Does it make a difference if we allow $f,g \in \mathbb{C}(x,y)$?

For example, $f=x$ and $g=\frac{1}{y}$ (what is the analog notion of being algebraically independent?).

Any comments are welcome! Thank you.

Comment: Is there a sufficient condition? sure there are plenty, including tautological ones. One would rather ask if there a necessary and sufficient condition checkable in terms of $f,g$ (say, which would be algorithmic when $f,g$ have rational coefficients).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Please, could you elaborate on what exactly that condition is (details/ideas not mentioned in the paper of Russell that may help in practice).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two polynomials that you are giving provide a morphism $\tau\colon\mathbb{C}^2\to \mathbb{C}^2$, given by $(x,y)\mapsto (f(x,y),g(x,y))$.

This map $\tau$ is dominant if and only if $f$ and $g$ are algebraically independent (which seems what you already ask).

This map $\tau$ is birational if and only if $\mathbb{C}(f,g)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$. This is also equivalent to ask that is is generically injective, which means that the preimage of a general point consists of one single point.

In practical, you can extend your morphism to a birational map from $\mathbb{P}^2$ to $\mathbb{P}^2$ by homogenising, and use Bézout Theorem: you find the common roots of the two homogenised polynomials in $\mathbb{P}^2$ (all these are on the line at infinity because the map is a morphism on $\mathbb{C}^2$). You then blow-up these and count the multiplicities of all base-points, including infinitely near ones. Then the map is birational if and only if $d^2-\sum m_i^2=1$, where $d$ is the degree (max of the degree of $f$ and $g$) and the $m_i$ are the multiplicities.

The article you mention are dealing with a related question which takes only one polynomial $f$ and try to find if it is a variable, i.e. if there is $g$ such that $(f,g)$ is birational.

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you please apply in a specific example what you suggested? In particular, I am curious to know when $f$ and $g$ of the following forms generate $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$: $f=a_{2n+1}y^{2n+1}+a_{2n-1}y^{2n-1}+\cdots+a_3y^3+a_1y$ and $g=b_{2m+1}y^{2m+1}+b_{2m-1}y^{2m-1}+\cdots+b_3y^3+b_1y$, $a_j,b_j \in \mathbb{C}[x]$, namely, $f$ and $g$ are skew-symmetric w.r.t. the involution $(x,y) \mapsto (x,-y)$.

Comment: Actually, I meant to ask when $f=f_{2n+1}+f_{2n-1}+\cdots+f_3+f_1$ and $g=g_{2m+1}+g_{2m-1}+\cdots+g_3+g_1$ generate $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$, where each $f_i,g_i$ is $(1,1)$-homogeneous of degree $i$. (For the above form it can be shown, thanks to Proposition 3.6 of Nagata's paper https://repository.kulib.kyoto-u.ac.jp/dspace/bitstream/2433/212692/1/1989-12.pdf,  that $\mathbb{C}[f,g]=\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ so $\mathbb{C}(f,g)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$).

Comment: The maps that you give (in both cases) are much too general to be able to compute it. You should give an example in practice to check.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to compute the case $\deg(f)=3$, $\deg(g) \geq 3$? Are there 'general' cases for which a computation is possible?

Comment: If $deg(f)=3$, then the zero set is a cubic. If this one is rational (irreducible with one cusp or a node), then there exists an element $h$ such that $(f,h)$ is birational. After applying the inverse of this, you reduce to the case where $f=x$, which is then easy: $(x,g)$ is birational if and only if $g$ is of the form $\frac{ay+b}{cy+d}$ where $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{C}(x)$ are such that $ad-bc≠0$. If $f$ is irreducible and not rational, then $(f,g)$ is never birational. If $f$ is not irreducible, you have to decide if you can send $f$ onto a line by a Cremona transformation.